# Activate a deactivated user in Okta

Tags: okta

It is unclear from the [API docs](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#user-model) if it is possible to activate a user in Okta once they have been deactivated.
I can see that they go to a deprovisioned status when they have been deactivated, and I know that the user will be pulled from any applications (all according to the documentation), but my question isn't answered in the docs.

Could I make an update to set the status of the user to "STAGED" and with an updated Profile object, and then call activate?

Answer (score 1):

In Okta Document I have seen "Deactivating a user is a destructive operation. The user is Deprovisionedfrom from all assigned applications that may destroy their data such as email or files. This action cannot be recovered!"

But I Deactivated the User and the Status was set to Deprovisioned, and by making Activate User Postman call I can set Provisioned Status again.

Here are the Okta Documentations call details to Deactivate and activate the user.
https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#deactivate-user
https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#activate-user

Simply try with postman It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the `STAGED` status, but I do know that you can re-activate a deactivated user.
Below is a `GET` request on a deactivated user:

```
{
    "id": "00ueq20eKcFJlFzHz355",
    "status": "DEPROVISIONED",
    "created": "2018-08-01T08:29:38.000Z",
    "activated": "2018-08-02T12:02:26.000Z",
    "statusChanged": "2018-08-02T12:03:38.000Z",
    "lastLogin": null,
    "lastUpdated": "2018-08-02T12:03:38.000Z",
    "passwordChanged": null,
    "profile": {
        "firstName": "Jim",
        "lastName": "Bean",
        "mobilePhone": "083274628237462",
        "secondEmail": null,
        "login": "jim.bean@test.com",
        "email": "jim.bean@test.com"
    },
    "credentials": {
        "provider": {
            "type": "OKTA",
            "name": "OKTA"
        }
    },
    "_links": {
        "activate": {
            "href": "https://mydomain.okta.com/api/v1/users/00ueq20eKcFJlFzHz355/lifecycle/activate",
            "method": "POST"
        },
        "self": {
            "href": "https://mydomain.okta.com/api/v1/users/00ueq20eKcFJlFzHz355"
        },
        "delete": {
            "href": "https://mydomain.okta.com/api/v1/users/00ueq20eKcFJlFzHz355",
            "method": "DELETE"
        }
    }
}
```

By sending a `POST` request to `https://mydomain.okta.com/api/v1/users/00ueq20eKcFJlFzHz355/lifecycle/activate` you can activate the user.